# Angular animation doesn't play on ngAfterContentInit without setTimeout

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, css-animations

I am trying angular animations for the first time, and I was wondering, why I need to wrap my toggle within a `setTimeout` when the component loads in order for the animation to play?

If I don't wrap the toggle within the `setTimeout`, then the side drawer is displayed right as if the animation already played. When adding the `setTimeout` back the animation plays as intended.

Using a `setTimeout` seems like it is a hack. Is there a better/correct way to do this that doesn't feel hacky?

**Edit:** Would It have to do with my hostbinding?

```
@Component({
  animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
      state('open', style({ transform: 'translateX(calc(100vw - var(--side-drawer-width)))' })),
      state('closed', style({ transform: 'translateX(100vw)' })),
      transition('open => closed', [animate('0.25s')]),
      transition('closed => open', [animate('0.25s')]),
    ]),
  ],
  template: `
<div [@slideInOut]="isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'" class="side-ddrawer">
  <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="userComponent; injector: userInjector"></ng-container>
</div>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  protected isOpen = false;

  @HostBinding('style.--side-drawer-width')
  protected width = 'var(--drawer-width--medium)';

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isOpen = true;
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the initial `scss` code when the component is created:

```scss
:host {
  --drawer-width--small: 360px;
  --drawer-width--medium: 600px;
  --drawer-width--large: 968px;

  --side-drawer-width: var(--drawer-width--medium);

  .side-drawer {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transform: translateX(100vw);
  }
}
```

Here is a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-t7462n?file=src%2Fmain.ts). If you uncomment out the `setTimeout`, you will see the animation start to work.

Comment: Is there any reason you are using the "ngAfterContentInit()" life cycle hook and not the "ngAfterViewInit()" life cycle hook?